# How to use WSL as default terminal in WebStorm or any other JetBrains' products?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am currently using Windows 10 with WSL Ubuntu 18.04 installed. I am trying to use WSL as the default terminal in WebStorm however, I am able to use the bash from WSL but the default directory would not be set to the default project location.

Does anyone know how to set this up correctly?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

After a bit of search on google found a solution to my question.

First figure out the default wsl with the command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wslconfig /list

Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu-18.04 
Legacy (Default)
```

then I set the default to Ubuntu-18.04 by

```
C:\Windows\System32\wslconfig /setdefault Ubuntu-18.04
```

Finally set the terminal path in Webstrom settings>tools>terminal to

```
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe
```

Now open the terminal it is correctly move the current directory to the /mnt/c/blah/blah

Comment: Thanks, this helps! I had `C:\Users\38093\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe` as a terminal path, but it didn't navigate to the project folder by default

Comment: Help windows terminal replace cmd by default,

useful answer

Comment: This also works for Rubymine. Thanks a lot forkadam

Comment: This is a great answer. I was looking for a solution to this problem for a long time!

Comment: This was written some years ago; after setting up WSL2, you only need to do that last step. The jetbrains IDEs default to starting in the project dir by default. Tested in Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 57):

**Set:**
Settings > Tools > Terminal > Shell path

**Equal to:**

```sh
"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe" run
```

[image: change setting]

---

The result is:

[image: resulting terminal]

Comment: I had to change it a bit for Ubuntu 20.04 like `"C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu2004.exe" run`

Comment: alternatively one can put "ubuntu1804" instead of full shell path which will also work fine.

Comment: B.T.W why is this configured globally, as each project may have a different shell? Also, each project may have a different shell that should be allowed to be configured, one windows, one unix etc..

Comment: In the WSL, you can run Windows executables that are on your Windows path, as well as any Linux tools you might want. So I highly recommend using it by default everywhere. (As to why JetBrains doesn't allow for more granular control, I don't know)

Comment: Im confused on why the hell everyones configurations are so different. Mine of none of these. This is complicated

Comment: @numerical25 maybe you need to install ubuntu first, take a look https://ubuntu.com/wsl

Answer (score 20):

`Settings -> Tools -> Terminal` change `cmd.exe` to `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` and restart Webstorm.

Comment: It also works with `bash.exe` or the better `wsl.exe`. I personalized my terminal and the latest one gets my customization.

Answer (score 15):

For me the version was fetched and set automatically, after I opened a project located in
`\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\my-user`.

Webstorm set the shell path to `wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu-20.04`

I use Webstorm version 2020.3 EAP currently

Comment: This is the only updated answer the others are not wrong but are outdated. More here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2020/06/webstorm-2020-2-eap-3/

Comment: Agree. The others arnt wrong but the exact path and different commands were never nessisay.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks bro, I use  "wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu"  in "File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal ->Shell Path field".

Answer (score 8):

Just adding an answer if you have multiple distros in your WSL and want to always use a particular one:

1. Find out what WSL distros you have with `wslconfig /list` and identify the one you want to use (in my case it's "CentOS7")

[image]

2. In your JetBrains product's Settings->Tools->Terminal, set the Shell path to `wsl.exe --distribution <whatever distro you choose>`. Example in CLion:

[image]

Click APPLY then OK.

Answer (score 7):

You can just set your terminal to `wsl` no path required.
Add `--distribution` to use another distro other than the default.

It's also automatic if you either, open a project from the distros own file system, or launch PHP storm from the terminal then the correct WSL distro will be used by the ide.

Comment: Using Webstorm 2020.3, setting the terminal shell path to `wsl.exe` works with no other settings changes required.  I have WSL 2 and Ubuntu 20.04 installed through the Windows App Store.

Comment: You can also append the user to change from root, ie `--user john`

Comment: Works on IntellJ IDEA 2022.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows builds 16215 and higher:

1. Install WSL and the Linux distro of your choice (I opted for Ubuntu 18.04)
   [Windows support docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)
2. Switch the default terminal to `bash`
   `Settings (or Default Settings)->Tools->Terminal->Shell path: bash`

I use Webstorm and Rubymine and in my case, that was all that I had to do.

PS Please note that the Webstorm update 2018.2 finally brings in full integration of WSL for Node interpreter
[Webstorm 2018.2 WSL](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/06/webstorm-2018-2-eap-182-3208/)

Also, Rubymine 2018.2 has drastically improved support for remote Ruby SDK (allows to use rvm), so now it is also super easy to use WSL/remote/containerized/dockerized Ruby env
[Rubymine 2018.2 released](https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2018/07/rubymine-2018-2-released/)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me for default setting the terminal to `zsh` but this did

In `phpstorm` I have setup the setting of terminal shell path as `bash.exe`

Tool > Terminal

> Shell Path: bash.exe

Then in the **.bashrc** I simply added the command at the end

```
/usr/bin/zsh
```

Now the terminal in phpstorm opens in zsh mode

Answer (score 0):

I found excellent hint. You can not change default terminal. Use only 2 steps from post **forkadam**

First figure out the default wsl with the command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wslconfig /list

Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu-18.04 
Legacy (Default)
```

then I set the default to Ubuntu-18.04 by

```
C:\Windows\System32\wslconfig /setdefault Ubuntu-18.04
```

**After it** drag & drop folder which you want to use in terminal windows. In WebStorm you can use "open in terminal" from context menu, but in Rider only drag & drop for open in wsl terminal with special path.

Answer (score 0):

- set shell path
  [image]
- edit Windows Terminal settings
  [image: edit terminal settings]
- ALT + F12

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the 'Workspace trust' setting was also a factor:
After following the above answers, I was still getting errors trying to start bash when I worked on WSL projects.  Coincidentally, I was getting these 'Do you trust this workspace' prompts on IDE startup (WebStorm).  Once I went to Settings|Build...| Trusted Locations and set the first entry to \\$wsl\Ubuntu-20.04\home\my-login-name  my shell finally worked -- whodathunkit? :)
HTH others - jps