# Configuring Remote (WSL) Composer in PhpStorm

Tags: php, composer-php, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to configure a PhpStorm project to utilize both remote PHP and a remote Composer. Remote being my Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) installation. However, when I initiate any Composer commands from PhpStorm, I get errors. And unfortunately, the errors are not very indicative of the cause or offer a link for additional details.

Errors received in my "Event Log":

```
12:21 PM    Composer
Failed to install packages for  ./composer.json.
Show in Log
```

And in my "Composer Log":

```
install --no-interaction --no-ansi
/bin/sh: 1: composer: not found
Failed to install packages for  ./composer.json.
```

So far, I've followed the instructions located at:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-product.html

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-remote-interpreters.html

I also followed the answer at this post to set WSL as my default terminal:

[How to use WSL as default terminal in WebStorm or any other JetBrains' products?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912772/how-to-use-wsl-as-default-terminal-in-webstorm-or-any-other-jetbrains-products)

In my WSL installation, composer is located at `/home/<user>/.local/bin/composer` and is included in my path upon login in my `/home/<user>/.profile` file. And I was sure to restart PhpStorm after doing so to ensure it has the updated path. Additionally, running `composer install` within my project, on WSL works without issue.

I'm not sure how to determine which terminal or composer file PhpStorm is using. Either it's still trying to find and use a composer on my host Windows install (which doesn't exist) or I'm missing a path which I have to map for WSL.

Any idea how I can obtain more details as to what I have misconfigured?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Fbin%2Fsh+%22not+found%22 -- in short, it looks like composer was not fully installed, simple as that. At least, it wasn't found using the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I found a lot on the web saying the same thing, but everything was extremely dated. I ended up finding this YouTrack issue which seems to indicate the feature was added in 2019.2.5.  

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23544

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my issue.

When in Settings -> PHP -> Composer, in the "Execution" section.  I was already selecting "Remote Interpreter", but the "Composer executable" field requires an absolute path. I was simply supplying the name of the executable since the field is asking for the executable.

I just figured it would utilize my $PATH to resolve the executable, but this isn't using an SSH session so it wouldn't have my custom $PATH values. So it all makes sense.